# Restrict bootstrap tooltip to trigger on all pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

How can I make sure my tooltip function shouldn't be trigger on all the pages and look for the tooltip on those pages as well where I don't have tooltip and in the end generate an error in console saying:

master.js
`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

HTML
`<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Sample Tip"></i>`

Error on pages without tooltip tag

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

*Currently I have added this code in master js which is referenced on all the pages*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your master.js simply check if `tooltip()` exists before calling it:

```
if ($.fn.tooltip) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understanding your question correctly,

One thing I might try is to add a class to the pages where you do not want the tooltips to show then destroy those tooltips 
ie.

```
<body class="no-tooltip"> ...
<script>$('body.no-tooltip').tooltip('destroy')</script>
```

Another , and probably a better option, would be to flip it around and in your master.js file only trigger the tooltip() on pages that have that 
`<body class="hastooltip">` and instead of you org function use

```
$(function () {
    $('body.hastooltip [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Comment: I have called $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); on master.js which is causing to look for data-toogle="tooltip" on all the pages. For those pages where I have tooltip is error is coming but for other pages (without tooltip) I am getting uncaught typeerror

<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Sample Tip"></i>